# んじゃ after a verb

Tags: grammar, particles

I have seen this sentence 待てよ おい 今から行ったんじゃ時間が…, can someone tell me what the 行ったんじゃ means? and describe me how the grammar works, or by any chance, provide me some source, where this exact usage is explained?

Comment: It is a colloquial contracted form of [のでは](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72517/43676).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a casual speaking version of Aのでは、B

### Conjugation rule

- Verb plain form/いadj（〜い） + のでは/んじゃ
- なadj（〜な）/ Noun + なのでは/なんじゃ

### Meaning

If A, B

Under those circumstances (A), B

**B includes expressions that express **a negative attitude****, such as "I'm in trouble" and "I will be having a hard time." etc.

### Example sentences

> こんなに仕事がいそがしいんじゃ、週末は休めないね。
>
> I can't take the weekend off, can I? when I'm this busy with work.

> 雨なんじゃ、しかたない。明日でかけよう。
>
> It can't be helped if it's raining. Let's go out tomorrow.

今から行ったんじゃ means "If we go there now,..."

### Note

You can use a verb plain form which means, you can use either present tense or past tense.
たform is often used in Japanese conditional forms.
You can think the meaning is the same in most cases regardless of the tense of a verb.
今から**行った**んじゃ、and 今から**行く**んじゃ、 I would translate to “If I go there now,…” for both of them.

For some specific verbs, there is a slight nuance difference, such as “じゅんびする (to prepare)”.

> 今からじゅんびするんじゃ、まにあわない。
>
> If I start preparing now, I won’t make it.

> 今からじゅんびしたんじゃ、まにあわない。
>
> If I prepare now (subtly implies that "even if I finish preparation), I won’t make it.

Comment: There was already a link to the previous explanation in the comment, but I added a little bit.